# Run WPF windows project on IE browser

Tags: c#, wpf

I developed WPF windows based simple application and now want to run on Internet browser. Is it possible to run on IE? need to know different way to do that, thanks

Comment: _Is it possible to run on IE?_ Did you tried anything?

Comment: read http://www.microsoft.com/silverlight/

Comment: Why do you think it would?

Comment: @SonerGönül i created WPF application right now and want to open this test app on internet browser(ie)

Comment: this link has an overview of deploying a WPF application as a XBAP which will allow you to run it in a web browser. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/aa970060.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Host it in a Silverlight application.  THis way you can run a WPF like designed app (XAML) in any browser.

Comment: I want to run my WPF window form on web interface like I.E

Comment: This is exactly what Silverlight does for you. Just create a new silverlight app. It creates 2 projects. The web project hosting the application. And the application project containing your xaml views.